XFCE: trigger desktop's right-click "Arrange Desktop Icons" from the command line or script?
I'm trying to use XFCE with Termux on Android, and the behavior of the desktop icons is a complete mess. The size of the display is dynamic (four possible configurations when using the phone, continuous variation possible when running in a window). The desktop icons are constantly shuffling themselves in a completely random way through successive screen size changes and its a disaster.
I'm happy with how Thunar places the dekstop icons with the "Arrange Desktop Icons" available in the desktop's right-click menu.
How do I trigger this action at login, and automatically each time the display size changes?

In XFCE, the desktop is handled by the command xfdesktop (not thunar as an older edit of the question had assumed).
If you run man xfdesktop, you will find that
xfdesktop -A

will auto-arrange the icons, and xfdesktop -R will redraw/refresh the desktop (in case effects are not immediately visible).
